# Class data members in a Silverlight-enable WCF Service

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, wcf-binding

I have class in my SVC file. I originally created it with only few data members. I have since add more. The problem is that when add these members don't appear when I call the service. I have a select query that populates these fields that appears to work because I can have them populate a different field and see my information. I don't even know how to began to trouble shoot this. I have attached my class.

```
public class LightOrder 
{
    public string SKU { get; set; }
    public string productname { get; set; }
    public string itemnumber { get; set; }
    public string asin { get; set; }
    public string amazon { get; set; }
    public double ourprice { get; set; }
    public string bbprice { get; set; }
    public int w1 { get; set; }
    public int w2 { get; set; }
    public int w3 { get; set; }
    public string w4 { get; set; }
    public int quantity { get; set; }
    public string rank { get; set; }
    public string ranking { get; set; }
    public string pendingorder { get; set; }
    public string afner { get; set; }
    public int cost { get; set; }
    public string order { get; set; }
    public string total { get; set; }
    public string profit { get; set; }
    public string percent { get; set; }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see any DataContract or DataMember attributes. Is this class part of the service contract via the ServiceKnownType attribute? If so, did you update the service reference after adding the new properties?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. But assuming that you are not able to access thies properties on the client side, I would suggest you update the service reference everytime a property is added to the service. The proxy generated on th client will only get the updated property when the reference is updated. Check in the Reference.cs file if your property is existing.

Comment: @Oliver I tried and succeded at updating the reference and I even went so far as to delete the reference and add it again and still the same issue. I am not sure about what is the reference.cs is.

Comment: Try creating the service host from a worker thread that should absolutely make sure the service won't run on worker thread.

Comment: @Oliver I made a new service and it appears to have been something with the old svc file.